# df is not displaying the entire space on device

Tags: filesystems, storage

The command

```
df -h
```

outputs the following

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              377M  1.3M  376M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.2G  504M  87% /
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop1                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/mmcblk1p2                     976M   78M  832M   9% /boot
/dev/mmcblk1p1                     511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              377M     0  377M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Which would sum up to around 12GB in total. However, the device should have a total of 32GB. Where do I find the rest? Also, I've noticed that if `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is at 100%, there is no space left on the device to store scripts etc.. So basically I only have 3.9GB available. How can I make the entire 32GB available for storage?

FYI I'm using a OnLogic CL210G-10 edge device

Edit:

```
sudo vgs
```

returns

```
 VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
 ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <27.62g <23.62g
```

And

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

returns

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 97 MiB, 101695488 bytes, 198624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 96.6 MiB, 101318656 bytes, 197888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 29.1 GiB, 31268536320 bytes, 61071360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 62E4C3F0-5C22-4483-98ED-8B82365DE29A

Device           Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1    2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk1p2 1050624  3147775  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p3 3147776 61069311 57921536 27.6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mmcblk1boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk1boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And

```
sudo df -hT
```

returns

```
Filesystem                        Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                              devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             tmpfs     377M  1.3M  376M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      3.9G  3.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                        squashfs   97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop1                        squashfs   97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/mmcblk1p2                    ext4      976M   78M  832M   9% /boot
/dev/mmcblk1p1                    vfat      511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                             tmpfs     377M     0  377M   0% /run/user/1000
```

And

```
sudo lvs
```

returns

```
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 4.00g
```

Comment: You seem to use LVM, so you probably haven't allocated all available space to your volume-group. What does `vgs` show?

Comment: You cannot sum up virtual devices like tmpfs stored in RAM with disk storage. Please show us `fdisk -l` command output so we know what disk and partitions do you have, so it can be verified with `df -h` output

Comment: @eblock thanks, I've edited my question to show the output of `vgs`. How would allocate the rest of the space?

Comment: What is the filesystem type of your LV? Is it the only LV in that volume-group? Edit the question with the output of `df -hT` and `lvs`. To increase the size of a LV by 1 GB you run `lvresize -L +1G ubuntu-vg ubuntu-lv`, and then you have to resize the filesystem, e.g. with `resize2fs` or `xfs_grow`, it depends on your actualy filesystem.

Comment: Edited the question to include the outputs." $ sudo lvresize -L +1G ubuntu-vg ubuntu-lv"
  resulted in "Please specify a logical volume path."

Comment: My bad, the command expects the device path: `lvresize -L +1G /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` should do it. Then for ext4 you need to run `resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot

Comment: `df -a` should give more output. be aware you can't see all behind chroot